# Get the list of directories whole Hadoop cluster with more than 50000 files

Tags: file, count, hdfs

Trying to get list of all directories in Hadoop cluster with files more than 500000.If a parent directory has more than 500000 files then the script should list the sub directories and do the hdfs count on them to determine the directory with more than 500000 files and list the sub directory of a sub directory and do the count to find the ultimate sub directory with more than 500000 files. This has to be done for the whole cluster starting with /

hdfs dfs -ls / | grep '^d'| awk '{print $NF}' | while read line | hdfs dfs -count $line| awk '$2 >500000 {print $1,$2,$3,$4}'

This lists only subdirectories of root, need to be able to do for the level for sub directory with 500000 omitting other sub directories with less files

Comment: Wouldn't `hdfs dfs -ls -R /` be faster to process than iterating a directory at a time?

Comment: hdfs dfs -ls -R / will go through all the directories , if I am iterating with directories the subdirectories of the directories with less than 500000 files will not be scanned.